# Anchor target doesn't work

Tags: codeigniter, anchor, target

I have a problem with the target tag of anchors. The anchor specification is:

```
<?php echo anchor(site_url('areaResponsable/perfil'), "Aquí", array('target' => '_self')); ?>
```

But, when I upload the project to the server, the links open in a new tab. And FireBug shows  the next anchor:

```
<a class="external_link" target="_blank"
 href="http://apps.manantiales.edu.ar/index.php/areaResponsable/perfil">Aquí</a>
```

Whats wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Could there be some javascript in place that dynamically adds `target="_blank"` to links with class `.external_link`? What happens when you remove that class?

Comment: try this echo anchor(site_url('areaResponsable/perfil'), "Aquí", 'target="_self"'); ?>

Comment: A minor point - you don't need to include `site_url` as the `anchor` function will automatically add this, so the first parameter can just be: `'areaResponsable/perfil'`

Answer (score 0):

I checked your website http://apps.manantiales.edu.ar/index.php and did a wget for all your js files. I found that a library named gebo_common.js is setting any link with 'http' in it as an external link. Which using site_url will use http.

The file http://apps.manantiales.edu.ar/js/gebo_common.js on your server has jQuery code to set the class 'external_link' to absolute urls.

So do this:

```
echo anchor('areaResponsable/perfil', "Aquí")
```